# Groups with Collapsing With Footer in Stimulsoft Reports

Tags: stimulsoft

I have some samples of Stimulsoft Reports (Demo-Reports).
I want to see how the groups can Collapse.

When I Open the Editor of "*Groups with Collapsing with Footer*", I can't figure out how can I Collapse the group with footer.

How does the Groups Collapse with Footer?

Answer (score 1):

You need enable the "Collapse GroupFooter" property:

- select GroupHeader,
- open the Interaction editor (from PropertyGrid or context menu),
- select the Collapsed tab,
- check the "Collapse GroupFooter" checkbox

[image: Collapse GroupFooter property]

Comment: But The problem that I have, I can't see the "Collapse" tab at the Interaction Property of 'Group Footer Band'. 

What should I do?

Comment: You must open the Interaction Property for the corresponding **GroupHeader**, not for _GroupFooter_